# How to use Singleton class method inside xml data binding?

Tags: android, android-studio, mvvm, data-binding, singleton

I have a singleton class in my android studio kotlin project and I want to use its method inside the xml.  For example, I have a variable inside the xml 
with the tag `@{appointment.startTime}`.
I want to format this appointment.start time using a global function and that function exists inside my singleton class with the name `parse(startTime: String)`, but I am not able to access that. I tried doing:

```
@{SingeltonClass.parse(appointment.startTime)}
```

But it is not working at all. I tried making a variable with the class type and tried to access that too, but it's not working with that one as well. Your help will make my day! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you please post more of your related code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one took me a little bit to figure out, but it's fairly straight forward. For this example I have custom primary colors that the user selects on a website that is reflected in the app. I store this color in shared Preferences and you will see a method called getSP PrimaryColorHex that is just calling an extension method to get it from SharedPreferences where it is loaded on startup of the app. Not important to the sample.

First you need to make your singleton and label the access function with JVMStatic so that it can be used to generate the databinding classes.

EXAMPLE:

```
class YACustomPreference private constructor(): BaseObservable(){

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STATIC ACCESSORS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    companion object {

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SINGLETON MEMBERS
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        lateinit var INSTANCE: YACustomPreference

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SINGLETON
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(): YACustomPreference {
            if(!::INSTANCE.isInitialized) {
                INSTANCE = YACustomPreference()
            }

            return INSTANCE
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Bindable
    fun getPrimaryColorHex(): String {
        return getSPPrimaryColorHex()
    }

}
```

Then you import it into your XML and use it.

EXAMPLE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <import type="com.appstudio35.yourappstudio.models.YACustomPreference" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@{YACustomPreference.getInstance().primaryColorHex}" />

</layout>
```

Also if you don't like checking it for initialization each time you could lazy load it like this:

```
class YACustomPreference private constructor(): BaseObservable(){

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STATIC ACCESSORS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    companion object {

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SINGLETON MEMBERS
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        val INSTANCE: YACustomPreference by lazy {
            YACustomPreference()
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // SINGLETON
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        @JvmStatic
        fun getInstance(): YACustomPreference {
            return INSTANCE
        }
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // METHODS
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Bindable
    fun getPrimaryColorHex(): String {
        return getSPPrimaryColorHex()
    }

}
```

Lastly, if you wanted to you could put the @JVMStatic over the member variable instead of the getInstance and use it directly if preferred. Also, remember the name must be different from the getter.

If you use

```
var instance -> auto generates property of getInstance setInstance
```

so having

```
fun getInstance() -> will create conflict
```

so come up with a unique name to avoid the conflict or just use the variable directly. I did all CAPS to avoid the conflict in this example.

Happy Coding!